# Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path Docker

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker

I would like to install some Django packages including `django-rest-auth` and `django-allauth`. These packages are able to be installed in my local venv but when building and running Docker containers they give `exit code 1` with the errors:

> Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Answer (score 3):

After doing extensive searching I found that it came down to the Docker Alpine image being a bare-bones image. Therefore you must install these dependencies in the Docker image as such:

```
RUN apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
```